# How Do I concatenate the items of a list to their corresponding values in the dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, concatenation

I am trying to get the following output

```
water:300ml
milk:200ml
coffee:100g
money:$0
```

The problem is that ml, g and $ are not part of the dictionary that I need to use and I can't convert the integers in the dictionary to strings because they need do be used in later calculations.

And of course the dollar sign is tricky because it has to be at the front.

I tried this code, but it doesn't work, and I just can't come up with an idea. TIA

```
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
    "money": 0,
}

for k,v in resources.items():
    levels= ['ml', 'ml', 'g', '$']
    print(k, ':', v)
    for level in levels:
        totals = (f'{v}{level}')
        print(totals)
```

Answer (score 5):

If you will reuse this operation, you could define a [string.Template](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.Template)

```
import string

template = string.Template("""water:${water}ml
milk:${milk}ml
coffee:${coffee}g
money:$$${money}""") # first 2 dollar signs are an escape to write the $
print(template.substitute(resources))
```

Which gives

```
water:300ml
milk:200ml
coffee:100g
money:$0
```

This might make it a bit easier to think about how you want the output to look.

The syntax here is to write `${var_name}`, and then have a corresponding key in your dictionary `'var_name'`. When you need to write a dollar sign, you must escape it with a double dollar sign `$$`.

Comment: I can't understand how the template is finding the keys of the dictionary without them being wrapped in quotes. Does the triple quote you put in take care of that, or this this a part of the Template method?

Comment: "I can't understand how the template is finding the keys of the dictionary without them being wrapped in quotes" to address this specifically, the parser looks for an unescaped `$`, and it then knows that the contents of the immediately ensuing braces `{` and `}` should match the key. Note that when a dictionary key has quotes around it, this just specifies that it is a string. The triple quote `"""` specifies a multiline string (and it is closed with another `"""`). Thus, the contents of the braces `{` and `}` are a string, which is directly comparable to a string key.

Answer (score 2):

You can move the levels list outside of your loop and access its indices with a simple counter.

```
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
    "money": 0,
}

    
levels = ['ml', 'ml', 'g', '$']
count = 0
for k, v, in resources.items():
    if k != 'money':
        totals = (f'{k}:{v}{levels[count]}')
    else:
        totals = (f'{k}:{levels[count]}{v}')
    
    print(totals)
    count += 1
```

Edit: You can also use zip to iterate over a dictionary and list at the same time. I think this is more pythonic than the counter above.

```
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
    "money": 0,
}

    
levels = ['ml', 'ml', 'g', '$']

for (k, v), level in zip(resources.items(), levels):
    if k != 'money':
        totals = (f'{k}:{v}{level}')
    else:
        totals = (f'{k}:{level}{v}')
    
    print(totals)
```

Comment: This is super cool, thank you. I was thinking about how I might use f strings, but I am still confused about how the variables in for loops work.

Comment: You just define your iteration variables on the for line and then each time through the loop, they access the next item in the iterable.

Answer (score 0):

One of the drawbacks of fstrings is that you can't use delayed expansion. You can always fall back on the old style though.

```py
format ={ 'water' : '%sml', 'milk' : '%sml', 'coffee':'%sg', 'money':'$%s' }
resources = {
    "water": 300,
    "milk": 200,
    "coffee": 100,
    "money": 0,
}
dict ( (k, format [k] % v ) for k,v in ressources.items() )
```